# Kotlin context sensitive generics

Tags: kotlin, generics

There are lots of examples of Kotlin generics but this is one I've not come across.

I've simplified it down to this:

```
open class Fruit
class Apple : Fruit()
class Orange : Fruit()

abstract class Helper<T : Fruit> {
    open fun save(something: T) {}
}

class AppleHelper : Helper<Apple>() {
    override fun save(something: Apple) {}
}

class OrangeHelper : Helper<Orange>() {
    override fun save(something: Orange) {}
}

fun process(theFruit: Fruit) {
    val myHelper: Helper<out Fruit>
    when (theFruit) {
        is Apple -> {
            myHelper = AppleHelper()
            myHelper.save(theFruit)     // this does compile (NOT expected)
        }
        is Orange -> {
            myHelper = OrangeHelper()
            myHelper.save(theFruit)     // this does compile (NOT expected)
        }
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
    myHelper.save(theFruit)   // this doesn't compile (as expected)
}
```

Using the `out` keyword for the `myHelper` variable makes it a *producer* of Fruit, however the 2 locations marked allow it to act as a consumer of `theFruit`.

The third location, as expected, rejects `theFruit` into the save method.

So clearly Kotlin is clever and can tell within the blocks that `myHelper` can be a safe consumer - but where is this behaviour documented?

Comment: This isn't really related to generics - it's simply that Kotlin can take the lines `myHelper = AppleHelper()` and `myHelper = OrangeHelper()` into consideration when type-checking the `save` calls. [Here is the part of the spec talking about this.](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#smart-casts) Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Sweeper that certainly seems to fit - I didn't even consider Smart Casts. Don't have things like that in Java :) Do you want to answer with that info and I'll mark as the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of Kotlin's smart casts ([documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) and [specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#smart-casts)).

The compiler does some dataflow analysis on your code and concluded that after the line `myHelper = AppleHelper()`, `myHelper` must be of type `AppleHelper`, `theFruit` must also be of type `Apple` because this is in the `is Apple` branch of the `when`. Therefore, `myHelper.save(theFruit)` is valid.

Whether or not generics is used is not relevant. Kotlin does this for everything. e.g.

```
val randomNumber = Random.nextInt()
val foo: Any
when (randomNumber) {
    1 -> {
        foo = "String" // here foo will be String
        println(foo.length) // can use properties specific to String
    }
    2 -> {
        foo = 10 // here foo will be Int
        println(foo * foo) // can multiply Ints
    }
    else -> {}
}
```